# If $X_1, X_2$ have exponential distributions what distribution does $Y = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$ have?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $P_{X_1}(x) = P_{X_2}(x) = k \exp(-k x)$ how will $Y = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$ be distributed? $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

**What I have Done:**
The distribution for $Y=X_i^2$ must be $\frac{k}{\sqrt{y}} \exp(-k \sqrt{y})$. To continue I must convolve this with itself, but I am not sure this is possible or whether I am taking the correct route?

I have also played around with numbers in Python... It seems that $P_Y \sim f(k) \, y  \, \exp(-g(k) \, y)$, but I cannot get a good fit of $g(k)$, so analytical result would be much appreciated.

Comment: To solve this, extra information is needed (like independence). Also meak it clear what is meant by $P_{X_i}(x)$. And what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: There is a good clue in the definition of $Y$. Try transforming to polar co-ordinates ($X_1 = Ycos \theta$ and $X_2 = Ysin \theta$).

Comment: If you put it into polar coordinates, you get something like $$P_Y(r) = k^2 r \int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp(-kr(\cos \theta + \sin \theta) ) d\theta $$ but I don't know how to integrate that exponential.

Comment: This is horrible, why do you think there might be an analytically result? my gut feeling is there is not.

Comment: The density $P_Y(r)$ looks analytic to me. You can differentiate inside that integral. It's just more of a question of whether there exists a 'nice' closed form for the density.